# Angular routes not making exact URL

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Angular routes zapping the parent and can go directly to the child when I'm expecting to give me a 404 page.
this is the route of the app module

```
{
 path: "mocha",
 loadChildren: () =>
  import("./navigation/navigation.module").then((m) => m.NavigationModule),
  
},
{
 path : "**",
 redirectTo : "error/404"
},
```

and this is the child route in the navigation module

```
{
path : "admin",
loadChildren: () =>
  import("./admin/admin.module").then((m) => m.AdminModule),
component : AdminComponent,
},
{
  path : "emplyer",
  loadChildren: () =>
    import("./employer/employer.module").then((m) => m.EmployerModule),
  component : EmployerComponent
  },
```

the 2 URLs: "/mocha/admin" and "/admin" giving me the same result, however, I'm waiting to give an error in /admin

https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-frog-vmqjf

Comment: If you try any url is redirecting to your 404 page? because I dont see the configuration for the 404

Comment: I have another module for the errors and its work fine example if I try "/adminn" this will give me to the 404 page .

Comment: Could you share a codesandbox or another working example, to review your code?, since everything seems to be fine in the code you share. Maybe is other configuration that is wrong

Comment: Not fully understood what you have, but you can check this:

- In children router modules (admin and employer), check if is used `RouterModule.forChild` instead of `RouterModule.forRoot`

- also, try to use `pathMatch: "full"` in rout definition

Comment: you can chek the problem here if you can try  the 2 urls "/admin" and "/mocha/admin"  I want to return error (404 page) when using "/admin" directly
https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-frog-vmqjf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was in the imports, I was importing the `navigation Module`

```
imports: [
    NavigationModule, // this module need to be deleted !
    Template Module,
    MatButtonModule,
    LayoutModule,
    
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this change to the child route in the navigation module:

```
 {
    path: '', // It will take the "base" route as defined in paerent route (/mocha/ in this case)
    children: [
       {
           path : "admin",
           loadChildren: () => import("./admin/admin.module").then((m) => m.AdminModule),
           component : AdminComponent,
       },
       {
           path : "emplyer",
           loadChildren: () =>
           import("./employer/employer.module").then((m) => m.EmployerModule),
           component : EmployerComponent
       },
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not mentioned in your posted code, but you have to make sure that you are not using the admin module directly in the app module, that could be the reason why you have /admin working.

Answer (score 0):

```html
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    redirectTo="error/404"
    pathMatch:full
  },
  {
    path: "mocha",
    component: MochaComponent,
    loadChildren: () =>
      import("./mocha/mocha.module").then((m) => m.MochaModule)
  }
];
```